# LSI Keywords - NLP Keyword Extraction - PHP RAKE/MAUI

Tags: php, regex, nlp, similarity, lexical-analysis

I am trying to find the best approach or algorithm to extract similar keywords from a given text.

I searched a lot, found RAKE/MAUI and other NLP algorithms, but they don't do exactly what I want. I don't want to enter a text and extract keywords, but I want to input a text + a main keyword, and extract keywords related to the main keyword somehow. Maybe Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm would be better?

Can you point me to a PHP script/algorithm that does this?
 For example, let's say we have the text:
"The **best plumbers from new york** are vey expensive. Working with a **plumber in new york** can be sometimes difficult, but in the end it will get the job done.
 A **cheap plumber** will make things harder, because usually he won't be very professional. **Emergency plumbing** can be found 24/7"

1) I would like to enter the keyword:
**plumber new york**

2) And the above text, and the script to return these keywords:
**best plumbers from new york**

**plumber in new york**

**emergency plumbing**

**cheap plumber**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a method that can see relations, RAKE, MAUI etc. will not do that for you. You could use them as a first step to get relevant keywords for the text. I suggest looking at graph based extraction like Page Rank.